# Comparing indexes of a list of tuples to a list of integers

Tags: haskell

I am very new to functional programming and haskell.

Basically, I have formed a list of tuples where they are ordered and indexed, like so

```
listOfCharTuples = [(1,H),(2,a),(3,s),(4,k),(5,e),(6,l),(7,l)
```

and as an input I will be given a list of ordered integers that will be at maximum, the number of tuples in this list.

I want a way to make a function that prints out the respective characters given the input of the list of integers, so if the list given was, for example [1,3,5], I would want the function to print "Hse".

I may be given any list of input characters, the only progress I've made so far is to make them into a list of indexed tuples, and I am really struggling to solve this

Comment: Try Hoogling for the type of the function you want: [`a -> [(a, b)] -> b`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+[%28a%2C+b%29]+-%3E+b). Even when you get the type wrong (as I did here) you get useful results. (I also tried searching for the monomorphic type `Int -> [(Int, Char)] -> Char` and still got the useful answer at the top. So this search, at least, is very forgiving.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible definition, using a list comprehension:

```
f :: [Int] -> [(Int,Char)] -> String
f is ts = [c | (i,c) <- ts, i `elem` is]
```

and then

```
f [1,3,5] listOfCharTuples
```

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the comment, a possible solution that is more general (does not require orderedness of the input) can make use of the [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

lookupAll :: [(Int,Char)] -> [Int] -> String
lookupAll tuples = map (\x -> fromMaybe '?' $ lookup x tuples)
```

Examples:

```
putStrLn $ lookupAll listOfCharTuples [1,3,5] -- Hse
putStrLn $ lookupAll listOfCharTuples [5,3,1] -- esH
```